# how to validate mobile number using input filter in entity ZF2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(
    array(
        'name' => 'phone',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'Int'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Between',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 10,
                    'max' => 11,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
));
```

It shows:

> The input is not between '6' and '10', inclusively.

Everytime it shows the same message in all cases even in empty

Comment: Disclaimer: haven't actually used it, but It may be worth looking at the `zendframework\i18n` package and in particular the `PhoneNumber` validator if you want to validate an actual number is a valid number according to locale -> https://github.com/zendframework/zend-i18n/blob/master/src/Validator/PhoneNumber.php Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be documented in the manual, but the unit tests may help with figuring out how to use it, see -> https://github.com/zendframework/zend-i18n/blob/master/test/Validator/PhoneNumberTest.php

Answer (score 1):

You want meant to use [the ZF2 `StringLength` validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.string-length.html#limiting-the-maximum-allowed-length-of-a-string) instead:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(
    array(
        'name' => 'phone',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'StringLength',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 10,
                    'max' => 11,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
));
```

As you see I would suggest handling phone number as a string in such case.

Answer (score 0):

When your validate an integer, the between option are the value of the int you input there. Not the length of it.

In this case :

55501015 is not between 6 and 10 inclusively.

7 is.

Your validator Between look like this :

```
public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);

        if ($this->getInclusive()) {
            if ($this->getMin() > $value || $value > $this->getMax()) {
                $this->error(self::NOT_BETWEEN);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->getMin() >= $value || $value >= $this->getMax()) {
                $this->error(self::NOT_BETWEEN_STRICT);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

It's not a check for the length, but the value.

Plus, if it's empty, the value of your int is clearly not between 6 or 10 so this is not a problem to me, if you wanna show that the value can't be empty you have tu use another validator in validatorChain.

You have to put it as string and control maybe via a custom validator with a regex on this string as follow :

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(
    array(
        'name' => 'phone',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'), // don't forget this one
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'StringLength',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 10,
                    'max' => 11,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
));
```